# PHP : Get current directory name

Tags: php, directory

I have a function that returns the current folder name:

```
function the_page_title()
{
    $page_name = dirname(__FILE__);
    $each_page_name = explode('/', $page_name);
    $len_page_dir = count($each_page_name);
    $c_i_p_n = 0;
    while($len_page_dir != $c_i_p_n)
    {
        $c_i_p_n++;
    }
    echo $each_page_name[$c_i_p_n];
}
```

However, this returns what `$page_name` holds and not the folder I am currently in.

When I `print_r($each_page_name)` I get this:

`Array ( [0] => [1] => home [2] => kyleport [3] => public_html [4] => inc ) /home/kyleport/public_html/inc`

Could anyone point me in the right direction because I have no clue where this is going wrong :( Thank-you!

In this case, I want it to display `inc`

Comment: Better turn warnings on. I suspect you'll see more clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just want the last element of an array:

```
$page_name = dirname(__FILE__);
$each_page_name = explode('/', $page_name);
echo end($each_page_name);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use;

```
echo getcwd();
```

This returns the current working directory on success, or `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, you should use `getcwd()` or, otherwise, your function will always return the folder where it's located instead of the current script directory.

Instead of explode, you could use `basename`;

```
function the_page_title()
{
    $page_name = getcwd(); // current script folder
    return basename($page_name);
}
```

```html
<title><?php echo the_page_title(); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the current directory with the predefined constant

```
__DIR__
```

which is the equivalent of

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

so you should use

```
$each_page_name = explode('/', __DIR__);
$dir = end($each_page_name);
echo $dir;
```

Answer (score 1):

This little line of code did it for me.

`echo basename(getcwd())`;

I just got the name of the folder I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code:

```
function the_page_title()
{
    $page_name = getcwd(); // getcwd() gets the directory of the file you call the function from
    $each_page_name = explode('/', $page_name);
    $len_page_dir = count($each_page_name) -1;
    return $each_page_name[$len_page_dir];
}
```

use:

```
<title><?php echo the_page_title(); ?></title>
```

Comment: Instead of showing the answer you accepted by writing it in a new answer, you should use the tick next to that answer.

Comment: I cannot accept my answer until tomorrow, I usually do... @worldofjr

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my suggestion to this list.
If you simply want to get the current folder name. You could just use `__DIR__` in combination with `basename()`

```php
<?php $current_directory = basename(__DIR__); ?>
```

An example of structure and returned content, if the above was added to the file.php:

`../directory-top/directory-sub/file.php` output > `directory-sub`